# how to serve static files through nginx and django in windows

Tags: django, nginx

I am a newbie. Just got setup the apache server in windows. But now I need nginx to serve my static files and I think I have searched almost everywhere how to configure nginx to serve static files, got many answers, but it was hard to understand. Can someone please explain where do I start from and how to configure nginx and django in windows in a noob's, perspective. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

edit the `nginx.conf` file located in the **conf** folder of the unzipped nginx for windows and add the following directive (You have to update the path to match the folder of your django project)

```
location /static/ {
        alias 'C:/Users/user1/your_django_project/staticfiles/';
    }
```

an example of your final `nginx.conf` could look like this if you are running a django webserver like hypercorn or other on port 8000 on localhost

```
http{
    server {
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Host 127.0.0.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP 127.0.0.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For 127.0.0.1;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias 'C:/Users/user1/your_django_project/staticfiles/';
    }
  }
  upstream backend {
      server 127.0.0.1:8000;
      # There could be more than a backend here
  }
}

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
```

**tested on nginx 1.20**

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your `server` section:

```
location /static/ {
    root /the_directory_with_your_files/;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry. I am not familiar with `server` section.

Comment: Ok, so how about you start posting the relevant part of your current nginx config for the rest of your setup? :)

Comment: Again, I am sorry. That's where am stuck. I don't know where or how to configure the nginx. Will you please kindly explain to me from the start.